# Cannot get FontAwesome to work in Razor

Tags: razor, font-awesome

This is my first attempt to use FontAwesome in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project. Following various articles, here is what I did:

1. Using Nuget Manager, downloaded FontAwesome package.
2. Added the following line in RegisterBundles() method:

`bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fontawesome").Include(
        "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css"));`

3. Added logic to use this bundle in _Layout.cshtml:

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/fontawesome")  // Added this line
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

Here is my simple Test.cshtml:

```
<h2>Test</h2>
<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
```

When displayed in browser, I don't see anything after "Test." Was expecting to see a star.

Here is the page source snippet from the browser:

```
<div class="container body-content">
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>

<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=8z6YzzH0c3lAT2R_qe2hLO3ZyowcuHmPA5RUiWrC6gU1"></script>
<script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=H2j5HUSj46jlSq1Se76I-uTAYq6y_MryNeOkhmo3adE1"></script>
<script src="/Content/fontawesome?v="></script>
```

I am wondering if I missed any step in using the font. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use @Styles.Render instead of @Scripts.Render for css bundles.

Answer (score 1):

As Varun mentioned, any Styles you bundle will need to be output with

```
@Styles.Render
```

rather than

```
@Scripts.Render
```

also not that you should ideally output your styles at the head above the instance of any fontawesome icons being used:

```
<html>
<head>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/fontawesome")
</head>

<body>
<div class="container body-content">
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed it but it still doesn't work. However, if I replace it with <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">, it works.

Comment: maybe if your script bundle is being optimized it may be falling over.  Looking at your code you included the minified version.  I've seen the script bundle fall over with certain minified files.  If this is the case then try adding the unminified version to the bundle, or for testing try removing the following line from your Bundleconfig.cs if it exists:  BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;